# Merge two dictionary in python with same keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I want to merge two dictionary in python with same keys

**The dictionary**:

```py
dict1 = { 'a1': { 'b1': { 'c1': 'd1' }}}

dict2 = { 'a1': { 'b1': { 'c2': 'd2' }}}

dict3 = { 'a1': { 'b2': { 'c3': 'd3' }}}

dict4 = { 'a2': { 'b3': { 'c4': 'd4' }}}
```

I want this to merge into

```py
dict1 = {'a1': {'b1': {'c1': 'd1', 'c2': 'd2'}, 'b2': {'c3': 'd3'}},
         'a2': {'b3': {'c4': 'd4'}}}
```

I have tried merging with `update` but it is overwriting everything

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:

The code I tried:

```py
dict1.update(dict2)
dict1.update(dict3)
dict1.update(dict4)
```

Output:

```py
>>> dict1
{'a1': {'b1': {'c2': 'd2'}}, 'a2': {'b3': {'c4': 'd4'}}}
```

Comment: Please post the code that your tried.

Comment: added code and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `update` only works at the top level.

```
def addin( d1, d2 ):
    for k,v in d2.items():
        if k not in d1:
            d1[k] = v
        else:
            addin( d1[k], v )

merged = {}
addin( merged, dict1 )
addin( merged, dict2 )
addin( merged, dict3 )
addin( merged, dict4 )
print(merged)
```